# python ternary operator with assignment

Tags: python

I am new to python. I'm trying to write this

```
if x not in d:
    d[x] = {}
q = d[x]
```

in a more compact way using the ternary operator

```
q = d[x] if x in d else (d[x] = {})
```

but this gives the syntax error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Python's dictionary get() method

```
q = d.get(x, {})
```

**Explanation:**

The get() method returns the value for the specified key if key is in a dictionary.

The syntax of get() is:

```
dict.get(key[, value])
```

**get() Parameters**

The get() method takes maximum of two parameters:

**key** - key to be searched in the dictionary

**value** (optional) - Value to be returned if the key is not found. The default value is None.

**Return Value from get()**

The get() method returns:

- the value for the specified key if key is in dictionary.
- None if the key is not found and value is not specified.
- value if the key is not found and value is specified.

Another option is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
q = d[x]

>>> q
>>> {}
```

Answer (score 11):

The conditional operator in Python is used for *expressions* only, but assignments are *statements*.  You can use

```
q = d.setdefault(x, {})
```

to get the desired effect in this case.  See also the [documentation of `dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Answer (score 4):

In Python, assignments cannot occur in expressions, therefore you can't write code like `a = (b = c)`.

You're looking for [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
q = d.setdefault(x, {})
```

Alternative, use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `else (d[x] = {})` is a syntax error is that in Python, assignment is a *statement*. But the conditional operator expects *expressions*, and while every expression can be a statement, not every statement is an expression.

Answer (score 1):

That's what [`setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) is for:

```
q = d.setdefault(x, {})
```

It does exactly what you want:

- Return `d[x]` if `x` is a key in `d`
- Assign `{}` to  `d[x]` if `x` is not yet a key and return that

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in the ternary operator (also called a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)), here is a way to use it to accomplish half of the original goal:

`q = d[x] if x in d else {}`

The conditional expression, of the form `x if C else y`, will evaluate and return the value of either `x` or `y` depending on the condition `C`. The result will then be assigned to `q`.

Comment: Well, this is an old question... Unfortunately, your answer is not correct - I was looking for a way to return an empty dict and to assign it to `d[x]` at the same time - something your code doesn't do (please check other answers). Still, +1 for the effort and welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I edited my answer to reflect its incomplete nature. Also, thanks for the warm welcome!