# Switch between assignments to different variables in python? With ternary operator?

Tags: python, coding-style, switch-statement, ternary-operator

I tried to use the python ternary operator to say something like

```
a = 1   if   test   else   b = 1
```

(where `test` has some boolean value), but this seems impossible (see also [python ternary operator with assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818992/python-ternary-operator-with-assignment)). So my question is: Is it indeed impossible or is there a more elegant way to do the task than

```
if test:
    a = 1
else:
    b = 1
```

Thanks already!

Comment: I think it is much more readable to have the if statement.

Comment: Your problem is that assignments are *statements* in Python, and the "ternary operator" is an *expression* (more correctly called the conditional expression). The conditional expression can form the right-hand side of an assignment statement, but you cannot use the expression as a way of combining two assignments on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to conditionally assign on only one line, but I don't consider it "elegant".

```
test = True
a = 23
b = 42
a,b = (1,b) if test else (a,1)
print (a,b)
```

Result:

```
(1, 42)
```

---

As an alternative approach, consider using a dictionary to store your `a` and `b` values.

```
test = True
d = {"a": 23, "b": 42}
d["a" if test else "b"] = 1
print d
#result: {'a': 1, 'b': 42}
```

Or, if the names have no semantic value, store your numbers in a list.

```
test = True
seq = [42, 23]
seq[test] = 1
print seq
#result: [42, 1]
```