# Ternary operator python not working on dict assignment

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

Today i'm trying to simplify this:

```
        for x in t:
            if x in hash:
                hash[x] += 1
            else:
                hash[x] = 1
```

To this:

```
        for x in t:
            hash[x] += 1 if x in hash else hash[x] = 1
```

Then i got an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
                                           ^
    hash[x] += 1 if x in hash else hash[x] = 1
Line 8  (Solution.py)
```

I thought i'm doing an expression here? as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818992/python-ternary-operator-with-assignment)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not really an answer, but `h = defaultdict(int)` will make your life easier, then you can just write `h[x] += 1`.

Comment: Looking at the question you linked, the answers seem to answer your question. For example, the top answer says "The conditional operator in Python is used for expressions only, but assignments are statements".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator returns a value, it does not support an assignment as a value (otherwise it would be a regular if/then/else)

You can use it like this:

```
hash[x] = hash[x] + 1 if x in hash else 1
```

BTW `hash` is a Python built-in function, you should not use that as a variable name.

*Note that there are other data structures in Python that might be  better suited to your purpose.  (e.g. collections.Counter, collections.defaultdict)*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
for x in t:
    hash[x] = hash.get(x, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Did you catch the ternary part?